# Passing in a function as an argument for event handlers in React

Tags: reactjs, constructor, ecmascript-6, bind

I'm working on refactoring some old, previously written code into ES6 for a React app, and have hit a small snag in the form of the snippets below.

```
modalCreateMethod={(e)=>{this.saveNow(this.buildItemFromForm(e))}}
modalSaveMethod={(e)=>{this.saveNow(this.buildItemFromForm(e))}}
```

I'd like to keep all bindings in the constructor as this application is quite large, but understand this may not be possible. I'm wondering what the best way to handle this is.

Using createClass, the old dev was able to just have this autobind. I'm trying to keep it clean and update the code so it continues working in the future. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: have you tried `modalSaveMethod={(e)=>{this.saveNow(this.buildItemFromForm, e)}}`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri trying this now. I keep getting error `Cannot read property 'modalSaveMethod' of undefined`

Comment: Not really understanding your problem, could you provide a minimal example?

Comment: That error would come if you are calling this method from a function that doesn't have proper binding

Comment: @webdeb using React.createClass, event handlers like the ones I've posted above autobind behind the scenes.

Comment: autobinding can be accomplished with class properties transform https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/

Comment: Sure, just store the `(e)=>{this.saveNow(this.buildItemFromForm(e))}` function in a property in the constructor?

Comment: @Bergi What do you mean? How would that work?

Comment: @AlexanderGlover Store the function as a property, then use that property to pass it as a callback to `modalCreate/SaveMethod`. If you can show us your complete class, I can post an answer.